# Using props in computed Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have computed property like this:

```
  display() {
     return this.labs.map(function(x, i) {
        return [x, this.plotDt[i]];
      });
    }
```

It receives the data as props:

```
  props: ["plotDt", "labs"],
```

Which are arrays of same lenght (I input two arrays: `[a,b,c]` `[1,2,3]` and expect to get mapped array: `[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]`

However somehow it does not work and when I check in VueTools I get message: `"error during evaluation"`
I dont really know what can be wrong in this case.

Comment: is `[a,b,c]` actually `['a','b','c']`? are they both the same length?

Comment: you might look at: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/missing-error-details-for-computed-properties/14723/6

Comment: @depperm Yes they are it works normally when I set those arrays in console and run that mapping method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround could be:

```
 display() {
     const vm = this;
     return this.labs.map(function(x, i) {
        return [x, vm.plotDt[i]];
      });
    }
```

And it is also possible that you need to go for method instead of computed. Mind sharing code pen?

Comment: Do you have any resource that deals with this case? Or did you just thought of this on the spot?

Comment: This in function is not related to vue instance probably, so it is just my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

`this` won't have scope inside the function unless used the arrow function or bind `this` with the `map`

The issue can be solved either like

```
display() {
 return this.labs.map((x, i)=> {
    return [x, this.plotDt[i]];
 });
}
```

or

```
display() {
 return this.labs.map(function(x, i) {
    return [x, this.plotDt[i]];
  },this);
}
```